# Html e-mail not being updated fast enough for smtp

Tags: html, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2008, smtp

Is there a known issue with SMTP and timing? I have included some code below that basically sends a birthday greeting to someone, along with a horoscope and other people that share their birthday (for fun).

I use Regex replace to get both elements, horoscope and other people, from other methods and insert them into the HTML document between a pair of "p" tags. I am positive that those methods work, and I am positive that the HTML document is being properly reformatted (according to the console, which prints out my new HTML document in another test of mine). I am thinking that maybe my problem is that the e-mail is sent off before the replacement has a chance to happen, but I could very easily be was off base. If anyone has had this issue before or knows the cause of it, I would be very appreciative. TIA.

`public void formatHTMLTest()`

```
    { using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("../../BirthdayMessage.htm"))

        {
            //Format the body
            //Format the Famous People
            string html = reader.ReadToEnd();

            string replacePattern1 = "<!--INJECT FAMOUS PEOPLE HERE-->";
            List<string> famousPeople = new List<string>();

            famousPeople.Add("test1");
            famousPeople.Add("test2");
            famousPeople.Add("test3");

            StringBuilder famousSB = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string person in famousPeople)
            {
                famousSB.Append(person + ", ");
            }
            int length = famousSB.Length;

            famousSB.Remove(length - 2, 2);
            string famousString = famousSB.ToString();

            string html1 = Regex.Replace(html, replacePattern1, famousString);
            //Format the Horoscope
            string horoscope = "FOO.";

            string replacePattern2 = "<!--INJECT HOROSCOPE HERE-->";
            string html2 = Regex.Replace(html1, replacePattern2, horoscope);


            //Configuring the SMTP client
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Port = 25;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("barfoo@sender.com", "senderPass");
            smtp.Host = "mysmtp";

            //Set up email that is sent to the client
            MailMessage clientEmail = new MailMessage();
            clientEmail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("barfoo@sender.com");
            clientEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress("foobar@recipient.com"));
            clientEmail.Subject = "Happy Birthday!";
            clientEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            clientEmail.Body = html;

            //using (smtp as IDisposable)
            {
                smtp.Send(clientEmail);
                clientEmail.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

I guess this goes without saying since I was able to get an e-mail, but just for clarity's sake, the SMTP has no issues also. I am fully able to receieve e-mails. The issue is that they do not contain the replaced html that appears in my console for other tests.

Also, any other things you see wrong with this code (optimizations, etc), don't hesitate to comment. I'm always willing to learn! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are injecting the string `html` into the body.  It should be `html2`?

Comment: You got it. Everyone else, disregard this post. My bad, got wrapped up in my own bad variables.